# How to add watermark on screen capture with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I edit user's screen capture (if they capture it in our app of course) and add our app watermark?

I have looked at screenshot & screenshot_callback packages but still can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use stack for widget (area you need to capture) and watermark and capture the stack.

```
ScreenShot(
  child: Stack(
```

Comment: but it doesn't trigger on device's screenshot (e.g. when users use capture using physical buttons)